# how much time logrotate waits between postrotate and compression

Tags: logrotate

I'm writing a software and I want to reload log files when the process get a SIGHUP from something like logrotate. The question is, how much time the application can use before logrotate starts compressing the rotated log file?

The manpage and all the references I found just states that the application must reload the logs "immediately", but doesn't say if this must be done in 1ms, or 1 second, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe: none at all.

Logrotate assumes that once the postrotate command has finished, the log file will not be written to anymore. There are two ways to deal with "closing log files might take a while":

- logrotate's `delaycompress` option postpones the compression step until the *next* logrotate invocation. That way, it can take up to however long it takes for the next logrotate run (although doing that would be a pretty bad idea).
- You can write a commandline tool which tells the daemon to close and reopen the log file, and make sure that this command does *not* exit until the daemon has confirmed that all log files have been closed (it doesn't need to wait until they've been reopened too, although that doesn't hurt). People can then use this commandline tool from logrotate's `postrotate` stanzas.